# Is it possible to use the remote grpc python plugin for `buf` to generate a Python Client Stub, but not generate the Servicer?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python, buf

I'm working with `buf` to try to generate code for my grpc service. However, I don't want to create a Python service. I only want to use a Python client to talk to my service. Is there some option I can give to buf, or the remote plugin to do this?

Here's my `buf.gen.yaml`

```
version: v1
plugins:
  - plugin: buf.build/grpc/python:v1.54.0
    out: gen/python
  - plugin: buf.build/protocolbuffers/python:v21.12
    out: gen/python
```

And my `example.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
package example;

enum MyEnum {
   Unknown = 0;
   Red = 1;
   Blue = 2;
}

message MyMessage {
  MyEnum my_enum = 1;
  uint32 some_other_field = 2;
}

service MyService {
  rpc MyCommand(MyMessage) returns (MyMessage) {}
}
```

And the generated file

```
# Generated by the gRPC Python protocol compiler plugin. DO NOT EDIT!
"""Client and server classes corresponding to protobuf-defined services."""
import grpc

import example_pb2 as example__pb2


class MyServiceStub(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    def __init__(self, channel):
        """Constructor.

        Args:
            channel: A grpc.Channel.
        """
        self.MyCommand = channel.unary_unary(
                '/example.MyService/MyCommand',
                request_serializer=example__pb2.MyMessage.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=example__pb2.MyMessage.FromString,
                )


class MyServiceServicer(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    def MyCommand(self, request, context):
        """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""
        context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED)
        context.set_details('Method not implemented!')
        raise NotImplementedError('Method not implemented!')


def add_MyServiceServicer_to_server(servicer, server):
    rpc_method_handlers = {
            'MyCommand': grpc.unary_unary_rpc_method_handler(
                    servicer.MyCommand,
                    request_deserializer=example__pb2.MyMessage.FromString,
                    response_serializer=example__pb2.MyMessage.SerializeToString,
            ),
    }
    generic_handler = grpc.method_handlers_generic_handler(
            'example.MyService', rpc_method_handlers)
    server.add_generic_rpc_handlers((generic_handler,))


 # This class is part of an EXPERIMENTAL API.
class MyService(object):
    """Missing associated documentation comment in .proto file."""

    @staticmethod
    def MyCommand(request,
            target,
            options=(),
            channel_credentials=None,
            call_credentials=None,
            insecure=False,
            compression=None,
            wait_for_ready=None,
            timeout=None,
            metadata=None):
        return grpc.experimental.unary_unary(request, target, '/example.MyService/MyCommand',
            example__pb2.MyMessage.SerializeToString,
            example__pb2.MyMessage.FromString,
            options, channel_credentials,
            insecure, call_credentials, compression, wait_for_ready, timeout, metadata)
```

Is there a way to tell the remote plugin that I only want to generate `MyServiceStub`?